# Analyzer message parsing

Tags: java, ftp

```
H|\^&|||DiaMed|CM v3.0||||||||20100510124259
P|1|10-001|4000011||Black^Carol|White|19670521|F||
O|1||4000011^^^\^^^|^^^MO01B|R|||||||||||||3||||20100510122212|||F
R|1|^^^AntiA^MO01B^Bloodgroup: ABO/D+ DAT (DiaClon) (5049)|0|C||||R||IH-
----------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
L|1|N
```

I got following message from Analyzer downloading from  FTP server.How can I determine it is a  complete message.  H indicate first character of message  and L indicates the end of the transfer session . I can get first index of message indicating H 
But How I can get last index indicating L from L|1|N.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reversing the whole String and selecting firstIndex?

something like

`int index = ((new StringBuffer(inputStirng)).reverse().toString()).indexOf('L');
index = inputString.length() - (index + 1);`


You will need to subatract from String length to get actual index

Comment: Thanks. If i want to reverse this process. I want to beginning character H and last termination character L, they how can I do it

Comment: Isn't this this original question...beginning character 'H' and last 'L'? Anyways do you get to know the beginning character and last character at run-time?

Comment: your answer is correct but i changed my approach for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can join all lines into 1 String. Then apply the following regular expression in DOTALL mode: ^H(.+?)L\|1\|N$

In the example below I'm using Groovy, mainly because it allows to define multiline strings. Other than that it should be straightforward to translate into Java.

```
import java.util.regex.*

def s = """H|\\^&|||DiaMed|CM v3.0||||||||20100510124259
P|1|10-001|4000011||Black^Carol|White|19670521|F||
O|1||4000011^^^\\^^^|^^^MO01B|R|||||||||||||3||||20100510122212|||F
R|1|^^^AntiA^MO01B^Bloodgroup: ABO/D+ DAT (DiaClon) (5049)|0|C||||R||IH-
----------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
L|1|N"""

String regex = '^H(.+?)L\\|1\\|N$'

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  String text = m.group(1);
  println text
}
```